# SQL.sql: Error (4,1): ORA-01951: ROLE 'CUSTOM_MASTER_ROLE' not granted to 'OPS$DOMAIN\USER'

Tags: oracle, roles

I am using someone else's database and if I try to revoke a custom role it fails with an ORA-01951 if the user does not have the role.

**SQL.sql: Error (4,1): ORA-01951: ROLE 'CUSTOM_MASTER_ROLE' not granted to 'OPS$DOMAIN\USER'**

How can I check in the SQL so I only try to remove the role if the user has the role?

The role creation is in a package I do not have the source code to so I do not know exactly how they created the role in the first place.

Comment: Are you asking how to check if a user is assigned a particular role or if there is a way to simultaneously check and remove role if exits. For second part - No, there is no such if exists that is part of revoke. For first part, you can query ```USER_ROLE_PRIVS``` or ```DBA_ROLE_PRIVS```. E.g. ```select * from dba_role_privs where grantee=<username> and role = 'CUSTOMER_MASTER_ROLE'```.  Possibly wrap the revoke within select and spool the generated output to a .sql file and then run that file. Is role exists spooled file will have revoke and will be revoke, else it will be an empty .sql file.

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj

I created a script that uses Execute Intermediate  to revoke the role.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create this code to do it.

```
declare
  hasRole number(1);
  v_sql varchar2(500);
begin
  select case 
           when exists(select 1 from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where 
           grantee = 'OPS$DOMAIN\USER' and 
           granted_role = 'CUSTOM_MASTER_ROLE')
         then 1
         else 0
       end  into hasRole
  from dual;

  if (hasRole=1) then
    v_sql := 'revoke CUSTOM_MASTER_ROLE from "OPS$DOMAIN\USER"';
    execute immediate v_sql;
  end if;
end;
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Your query works but a bit complicated. I would use

```
For aRow in (select * from 
       DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where 
       grantee = 'OPS$DOMAIN\USER' 
       and granted_role = 'CUSTOM_MASTER_ROLE') 
LOOP
   v_sql := 'revoke CUSTOM_MASTER_ROLE from "OPS$DOMAIN\USER"';
   execute immediate v_sql;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Thanks this does look cleaner than mine. Appreciate the reply. I will use your method..